# Error al instalar el package "dominanceanalysis" en RStudio versión 4.1.2

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando instalar el paquete "dominanceanalysis" en la versión de RStudio 4.1.2 y me aparece el siguiente error:

> package ‘dominanceanalysis’ is not available for this version of R A
> version of this package for your version of R might be available
> elsewhere, see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Entonces, quería preguntar si alguien me puede decir cómo puedo instalar este paquete en mi versión de RStudio.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `dominanceanalysis` ha sido "archivado" en `CRAN` que es una forma de decir que ya no está disponible para la instalación directa. Por lo que se menciona [aquí](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dominanceanalysis/index.html) el paquete no ha resuelto algunas verificaciones en tiempo y forma. Cuando esto ocurre, podemos llegar a tener tener dos alternativa, no siempre es así:

#### 1. Instalar el paquete desde las versiones archivadas

Por ejemplo, en este caso, la [página](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dominanceanalysis/) de `CRAN` nos indica que la última versión que tienen archivada es (aparentemente) la 2.0.0

```
download.file('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dominanceanalysis/dominanceanalysis_2.0.0.tar.gz',
              'dominanceanalysis_2.0.0.tar.gz')

install.packages('dominanceanalysis_2.0.0.tar.gz', 
                 repos = NULL, type="source")
```

### 2. Instalar desde `github`

Como en este caso, el proyecto parece estar mantenido en [`github`](https://github.com/clbustos/dominanceAnalysis), mediante el paquete `devtools` podremos hacer:

```
devtools::install_github("clbustos/dominanceAnalysis")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda Patricio.
Voy a intentar instalar el paquete siguiendo tus instrucciones y te contaré como me ha ido. Un saludo y de nuevo muchas gracias